# how to write a custom loss function in keras?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

Here is the model I am writing the custom loss function for:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(2,2,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(8,8,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=custom_loss1, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is the `custom_loss1` function I wrote:

```
import keras.backend as kb

def custom_loss1(y_actual, y_predicted):
    value = kb.mean(kb.sum(kb.square((y_actual-y_predict)/10)))
    return value
```

But I am getting this error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_45/kernel:0', 'conv2d_45/bias:0', 'dense_45/kernel:0', 'dense_45/bias:0'].

What to do?

Comment: Please add`model.fit()` line.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure without actually running the code itself but did you try in tensorflow:

```
adj_diff = (y_actual - y_pred)/10
diff_squared = tf.math.square(adj_diff)
sum_diff = tf.math.add(diff_squared) ## or tf.math.reduce_sum depending on your dimensions
return tf.math.reduce_mean(sum_diff)
```